# before(:create) in factory based on some condition with factory-girl gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I have using `factory_girl` gem version:4.4.0 with `ruby-1.9.3-p429`. I am  using `before(:create)` in one of the factory as follwing:

```
factory :entity1 do
      b_date  Time.now
      a_date  Time.now
      event   "test_event"

      before(:create) { FactoryGirl.create(:entity2)  }
end

factory :entity2 do
      from_date  Date.today - 1.day
      till_date  Date.today + 1.day
end
```

Now there is a unique condition on `from_date` and `till_date` on `entity2`, in other words I want to create `entity2` only once. Is there some `if` condition I can introduce in factory of `entity1` so that `before(:create)` clause get executed only first time I create `entity1` and from next time onwards it doesn't create `entity2`.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get around your uniqueness issue is to look for an existing model before creating one:

```
before(:create) do
  Entity2Model.find_by_unique_field('value') ||
    FactoryGirl.create(:entity2)
end
```

However, I'd also take this as an opportunity to ask yourself some questions about this dependency:

- If there's only ever one instance of `entity2`, does it need to be in the database?
- If there's only ever one instance of `entity2`, does it make more sense as a singleton method than an association?
- Does `entity1` really need `entity2` to exist every time it's used? If so, can they be decoupled?

**Update:**

If it's just a uniqueness constraint and you can have more than one, you can use a sequence to generate unique values of `entity2`:

```
factory :entity2 do
  sequence(:from_date) { |n| n.days.ago }
  till_date { from_date + 1.day }
end
```

Comment: There can be multiple instances of `entity2` as it can have multiple values, just that there is a unique constraint on those two fields.

Yes `entity1` really needs `entity2`, what I can do is stub few function in the test to get rid of this dependency.